# Windows 7 cannot boot to disk or usb

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, bootable-media, ubuntu-13.04

I have a Toshiba laptop that was a Windows 8 OEM. I recently reinstalled Windows 7 onto the laptop using the boot to disk option within the windows 8 recovery screen.

I am now trying to dual boot Ubuntu with it. There is no option in the boot menu or BIOS for a cd/dvd as a boot device. only HDD, ODD, and USB. Note: The option wasnt available with Windows 8 still on it, I had to use the option within the Windows 8 recovery screen.

BIOS Details: I turned off secure boot, turned CSM boot on.

So as a workaround I made a bootable USB instead and changed the USB to first in the boot order and attempted that. No luck at all. It seems that the USB doesnt power on until Windows is fully started.

Anyone have some ideas? I can provide more info to anyone if needed.

Thanks

Comment: ODD = Optical Disk Drive.

Comment: What tool did you use to create the bootable sb drive?

Answer (score 0):

Strange that the laptop bios hasn't got the option to boot from CD/DVD Drive, I can only assume this a netbook, try an external DVD drive, the bios will detect it on boot and show up in bios.  Also most laptops have a boot sequence interrupt key which will let you choose which device to boot from by holding down a F key on boot, you may have to turn the logo screen off to show boot diagnostic screen from within bios or can press TAB while bios screen appears also to find out what the F key is, hope it helps.